# Inline Installation on Blogger not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have a Blog powered by Blogger [[PhysicsGames.tk]](http://www.physicsgames.tk)

Also I have an application on Chrome Web Store [THIS ONE](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hnmdbeamhkbhfobfmoaemhpfcgejlbif)

So I've been using the [Inline Installation](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/inline_installation) it worked well, unfortunately. I realized today that no longer works...

In the website main template I added the following code:

```
<link href='https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hnmdbeamhkbhfobfmoaemhpfcgejlbif'
      rel='chrome-webstore-item'/>
```

And I create a button:

```
<a onclick="chrome.webstore.install()" href="#">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/D8ul8.png"/>
</a>
```

So It should work like this:

1. On the websiste, I click the 'button' and a dialog like [this](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/images/imageAssets/inline_install_dialog.png) should appear, that is a application installation verification dialogue.
2. Then If you click on "Add" the app should install.

Well in my case, stays in step 1, the dialog never appears.
What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my English.

Comment: have you found the solution of this problem. I am also stuck with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<link href="..." rel="chrome-webstore-item">` needs to be in the `<head>` section of your page. Your page actually has it in between the `<head>` and `</head>` tags, but if you inspect the page's DOM, you'll see that the `<link>` tag is actually shown in the body:

[image: DOM screenshot]

This is because you have a `<itemscopetag>` (generated by Blogger presumably) before the `<link>` tag, which is unknown, and is causing the `<head>` section to be ended early (this behavior is [defined by the HTML spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tree-construction.html#parsing-main-inhead)).

In some ways, this is a Blogger bug (it shouldn't be putting unknown tags into `<head>`), but in the meantime, one fix is to move the `<link>` tag so that it's above the `<itemscopetag>` one.

Comment: Nice spot @mihai. I was seeing the `Uncaught No Chrome Web Store item link found.` error but wasn't finding any obvious reasons why it wasn't finding the link.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just adding the link line inmediately above of "<head>" tag. I hope it works :/

Comment: @Mihai Parparita I am still stuck with this problem. Can anybody help me